# Error in lda.default(x, grouping, ...) : variable 74 appears to be constant within groups

Tags: r, regression, linear-model, linear

I did a Linear Discriminant Analysis using R and the output given was Error in lda.default(x, grouping, ...) :    variable 74 appears to be constant within groups. My codes are

library(MASS)

attach(yan)

indexes = sample(1:nrow(yan), size=0.5*nrow(yan))

train50 <- yan[indexes,]

test50 <- yan[-indexes,]

ldafit<-lda(income~.,data=train50)

yan is the name given to the original dataset and
Income is the response variable

I suspect that its because my 74th variable hace a co-releation with my other variables, thus there is this error. Could anyone help in resolving this?. Thanks

Comment: Co-linearity can cause this error by causing the covariance matrix to be singular (non-invertible). Does this go away when you remove your 74th variable?